# Table View Delete from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I've managed to add data to a table view and import that to the specific Firebase location. I now want to be able to delete this data from inside the application.

Currently, with this code the entry successfully deletes from within the app, but not Firebase and when the app is reopened the entry returns. Basically I would like to know what I've done wrong and what I can change to actually delete the entry from the real time database.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class WorkoutNotesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

var addExer:[String] = []
var handle: DatabaseHandle?
var ref: DatabaseReference?
var keyArray: [String] = []

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var exerView: UITextField!
@IBAction func inputButton(_ sender: Any) {

if exerView.text != ""
{
    ref?.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("notes").childByAutoId().setValue(exerView.text)
        exerView.text = ""
    }
else
    if exerView.text == "" {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Retry", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return addExer.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = addExer[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true

    ref = Database.database().reference()

handle = ref?.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("notes").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let item = snapshot.value as? String
    {
        self.addExer.append(item)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    })

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        GetAllKeys()
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: {
            self.ref?.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("notes").child(self.keyArray[indexPath.row])
            self.addExer.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            self.keyArray = []
        })
    }

}

func GetAllKeys() {
    ref?.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("notes").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            self.keyArray.append(key)
        }
    })
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to embed `removeValue()`

```
self.ref?.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("notes").child(self.keyArray[indexPath.row]).removeValue()
```

Also it's better to use a completion to be 100% sure that the item is deleted from firebase

```
 self.ref?.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("notes").child(self.keyArray[indexPath.row]).removeValueWithCompletionBlock({ (error, refer) in
   if error != nil {
      print(error)
   } else {
      print("Child Removed successfilly")
  }
```